# Не выводить повторяющиеся значения [MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных есть 5 строк, с полем **description**(описание). В каждой из строк в поле **description** есть хэштег "**#istanbul**".

В **1-ой** строчке - **"#istanbul"**,
Во **2-ой** строчке - **"#IstanbulNight"**,
В **3-ей** строчке - **"#Istanbul"**,
В **4-о**й строчке - **"Hello and #WelcomeToIstanbul"**,
В **5-ой** строчке - **"My first travel to #Istanbul"**,

Мне необходимо вывести все строки, у которых в поле **description** есть в хэштегэ слово "**istanbul**". Одинаковые значение не должны повторяться, например:

Должны выводиться **только** **1**, **2**, **4** строка, так как **3** и **5** идентичны **1-ой** **не учитывая регистр**. Необходимо убрать только те сроки, в которых **один** единственный хэштег **"#istanbul"**

Мой код:

```
$GetQUERY = "#istanbul";

SELECT * FROM `".PREFIX."_photos` WHERE description LIKE'%{$GetQUERY}%' ORDER by `uploaded_date` ASC
```

Хотел использовать **SELECT DISTINCT**. Не помогает. Подскажите как решить данную проблему

***P.S. я новичок, строго не судить***

Comment: $result = array_unique($arr); запиши выборку в массив $arr. и прогани

Comment: @Bloom, это не поможет для строки `5`.

Comment: вначале избавимся от одинаковых, потом будем решать проблему дальше

Comment: Дело в том что, некоторые строки содержат несколько хэштегов, например "My first travel to #Istanbul, and #GotoIstanbul"

Comment: "My first travel to #Istanbul, and #GotoIstanbul"  тоже убрать надо или оставить?

Comment: Вывести. В общем убрать только те, в которых только один хэштег - #istanbul. Надеюсь смог сформулировать

Comment: @KamranMusa, а просто в where добавить условие LIKE'%{$GetQUERY}%' AND '%{$GetQUERY}%' <> "#istanbul" не проходит ? или я не правильно понял что нужно

Comment: неправильно выше написал  '%{$GetQUERY}%' <> "#istanbul" здесь должно быть : '.$GetQUERY.' <> "#istanbul" ну или экранировать символы при составлении строки запроса (смысл именно в том что бы запретить этот 1 хештег по условию выборки без php-шных обработок)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так отберутся строки, в которых есть тег, отсутствующий в предыдущих

```
$arr =  [
  "#istanbul",
  "#IstanbulNight",
  "#Istanbul",
  "Hello and #WelcomeToIstanbul. You are in #istanbul now",
  "My first travel to #Istanbul",];

// сюда собираем все найденные теги
$prev = [];

$r = [];
foreach($arr as $x) {
    if(preg_match_all('~#\w+~', $x, $match)) {
        // если надо не зависеть от регистра 
        $match[0] = array_map('strtolower', $match[0]);
        // если все уже были, пойдем дальше
        if( ! ($d = array_diff($match[0], $prev))) {
            continue;
        }
        // добавим новые, обнаруженные в строке 
        array_push($prev, ...$d); 
    }
    $r[] = $x;
}

print_r($r); // [ '#istanbul', '#IstanbulNight', 'Hello and #WelcomeToIstanbul. You are in #istanbul now']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `".PREFIX."_photos` WHERE description LIKE'%{$GetQUERY}%' ORDER by `uploaded_date` ASC";
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$data[]=$row;
}    
$data=array("0"=>"#IstanbulNight",
    "1"=>"#Istanbul",
    "2"=>"Hello and #WelcomeToIstanbul",
    "3"=>"My first travel to #Istanbul",
    "4"=>"My first travel to #Istanbul, and #GotoIstanbul",
    "5"=>"#Istanbul");

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        # code...

    $pos=strpos($value,"#Ist");

    if($pos===false){

    $big[]=$value;

    }else{

    $nig[]=$value;

    }

    }

    print_r($nig);
    $result = array_unique($nig); 
    print_r($result);
```